# Veracrypt: Possible to add encryption-algorithms and/or hash-algorithms?

Tags: encryption, veracrypt

Is it possible to add encryption algorithms or hashing algorithms to Veracrypt?

Like, for example: A Veracrypt-container encrypted with e.g threefish?

Or a similar question: to change the order of encryption algorithms to your own liking?

Like from: AES(Twofish(Serpent)) to:  Twofish(AES(Serpent))

Comment: That is something you should look up in the Veracrypt documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veracrypt is open-source, and thus anybody is able to modify and rebuild the code.

So, yes, one could add or modify cryptographic functions in the application by modifying the code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible without modifying the source code of VeraCrypt. The algorithms and the cascade order requires explicit support in the program. Even if you could add new ciphers, you couldn't make them arbitrary. This is due to the fact that VeraCrypt, when given a password, will test it against every cipher combination it knows of to see which one is correct. The more combinations of ciphers, the longer this takes. It would be impossible to support arbitrary ciphers or cascades because it would require trying each and every possible combination of ciphers to unlock a volume.